# Pascal's Triangle's different usages

Tags: binomial-coefficients

[image: Pascal's Triangle]
This is Pascal's Triangle, whose $(r + 1)$th row show the coefficients of $(1+x)^r$   expanded. It is used to find the expansions of $(1+ x)^n$, and also $nPr$. Are there any other significant uses of the Pascal's Triangle?
Unlike the post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714839/how-is-pascals-triangle-important), I am not looking for properties, I am looking for practical uses.

Answer (score 0):

**[Source](https://prezi.com/m/ns63yt572bto/pascals-triangle/)**:

> In the real world, Pascal's Triangle translates into the complex topic of graph theory who've includes turning mapping information into data, finding shortest paths, airplane rules and airport control, computer graphics, engineering, data management, search algorithms and more.
>   Pascal's Triangle is also often used in Architecture and design, because since buildings are 3-D, using Pascal's Triangle in expansions and measurements is common.

Also see whether [this](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-real-world-examples-of-the-use-of-the-binomial-theorem) helps you. Hope it helps.

Comment: Could you maybe give something specific please, and also explaining it. Thanks.

Comment: @simplest_mathematics I tried to give the best possible result from Google. However also see the link I have provided.

Comment: Okay, but thanks anyway!

Comment: @simplest_mathematics You can up vote and accept it if you like.